# What happens if I use a proxy through software such as Proxifier and also use a software which supports working through proxy servers?

Tags: proxy, ip

Let me give you an example:

I use proxifier to use a proxy that uses IP from Germany. So when I check https://www.whatismyip.com/ it shows as if I'm from Germany.

So imagine if I have a software on my PC which supports working through proxy servers and I enter a French proxy different from the one from Germany. Will the admins of that software see that my IP is from France or Germany?

Answer (score 1):

Let's use Firefox as the software you use.

First, you proxify Firefox, and set the proxy to *No proxy*. Every request will be routed to Germany (e.g `germany-proxy.de`) and your IP will show as coming from Germany. Nothing unexpected here, right?

Next, you configure Firefox and use a proxy on France (e.g `france-proxy.fr`). Firefox will try to connect to `france-proxy.fr`, and the request is intercepted by the proxifier. The connection gets redirected to `germany-proxy.de`, which will establish the connection to `france-proxy.fr`. On this moment, `france-proxy.fr` thinks you are from Germany, and `germany-proxy.de` knows where you are. The destination have not received anything from you yet.

If Firefox connects to, let's say, Google, is `france-proxy.fr` the one connecting, so Google will think you are connecting from France. France will think you are connecting from Germany, and Germany knows where you live.

That's a oversimplified version of Tor. On Tor, you connect to a proxy, that connects to another one, that connects to another one . . . that connects to the destination, and every hop is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the particular software. For example, if you use firefox over proxychains and set a different proxy in firefox settings, firefox will be stronger and escape proxychains. If you use whonix-gateway instead of proxychains, the traffic will be first routed through tor and then through the proxy you set in firefox, so whatismyip.com will show the proxy set in firefox this time as well. But in some cases programs might stop using proxy if they know another proxy software is in action, although I have never experienced this.